# Find the time complexity of bubble sort?

Tags: c, algorithm

Can anyone help me in finding the time complexity of the following bubble sort function? I'm really having a hard time doing this. It would be really helpful if anyone can help me on this. Below is my code:

```
void bubble_sort ( int n )
{
    int i, j, k, temp ;
    struct link *p, *q ;
    k = n;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n - 1 ; i++, k-- )
    {
        p = head ;//Sorting the linked list in descending order for displaying
        q = p ->next ;

        for ( j = 1 ; j < k ; j++ )
        {
            if ( p -> freq < q -> freq )//checking frequencies for sorting
            {
                temp = p ->freq ;
                p -> freq = q -> freq ;
                q -> freq = temp ;
            }
            p = p -> next ;
            q = q -> next ;
        }
    }//Sorted linked list
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  What have you tried?  Are you seeking empirical evidence, or are you doing it theoretically?  It is an odd function that relies on `head` as a global variable that points to the start of a list, and takes an argument `n` as the number of entries in the list to sort.  What happens if the list is shorter than `n`?  Longer?  Normally, you'd pass the head of the list to the function and sort the entire list.  You should really create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and include that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's compute the number of operations:

- The outer loop runs `n-1` times
- For each iteration, the inner loop runs `n - i - 1` times.
- the bulk of the code is inside the nested loop: a comparison, a swap operation and 2 pointer modifications: **O(1)** time.

The overall number of operations comes out at **(n * (n - 1) / 2) * O(1)**

Therefore the time complexity of the above code is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a classical Bubble-sort.
So in Worst-case and average-case this is O(n²).

for more information: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bubble_sort#/Performance